# How to use printf in this Helm template function?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I created this Helm template function in my `templates/_helpers.yaml` file. It simply gets the gets the value of an array element (the `index .Values...` part), based on the passed-in environment. It works fine.

```
{{/*
Function to get min CPU units
*/}}
{{- define "microserviceChart.minCpuUnits" -}}
{{ index .Values.valuesPerEnvironment.cpuUnits ((pluck .Values.environment .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int) | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

For example, in my values.yaml file

```
environments:
  sandbox: 0
  staging: 1
  production: 2
valuesPerEnvironment:
  cpuUnits: [512, 512, 1024]
```

so my template function returns `"512", "512", "1024"` based on my passed-in environment. However, can I use printf to it adds `m` to these values? **In other words**, I want it to return `"1024m"` for production. I tried the following but I get a syntax error

```
{{/*
Function to get min CPU units
*/}}
{{- define "microserviceChart.minCpuUnits" -}}
{{- printf "%dm" index .Values.valuesPerEnvironment.cpuUnits ((pluck .Values.environment .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int) | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the arguments in the right order for `printf`, you could include the `m` in the template body.  You'll also need to make the `"..."` explicit, instead of using the `quote` function, to get the `m` inside the quotes.

Expanded out (note that `{{-` and `-}}` will delete whitespace before and after, including newlines):

```
{{- define "microserviceChart.minCpuUnits" -}}
"
{{- index .Values.valuesPerEnvironment.cpuUnits ((pluck .Values.environment .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int) -}}
m"
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Excellent trick! I used it in other functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The heck with it. I just made my `values.yaml` like this, and I get the same result.

```
environments:
  sandbox: 0
  staging: 1
  production: 2
valuesPerEnvironment:
  cpuUnits: [512m, 512m, 1024m]
```

It'd still be cool to know if I can do this in the function, so if someone answers the actual question, I'll accept that as the answer.