# In Helm, how to get the index of an array alement?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I read [List and List Function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) but didn't find what I needed.

I have the following in my `values.yaml` file.

```yaml
# Default environment
environment: sandbox

environments:
- sandbox
- staging
- production
```

How can I get the index value of the `environments` array based on a passed-in `environment` during a `helm install --set environment=xxx` command? So if I don't pass a value, I get `0` since the default environment is `sandbox`. If I pass `--set environment=production`, I get `2`.

I think I need the opposite of the `index` function.

Note I know I can do a map

```yaml
environments:
  sandbox: 0
  staging: 1
  production: 2
```

and have

```
index .Values.environments .Values.environment
```

But there's got to be a way to do what I want to do with an array?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's not a "find" type function that returns the index of a value in a list (or the key matching a value in a map).  [Go template: is there any item in list of objects with a specific attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73858918/go-template-is-there-any-item-in-list-of-objects-with-a-specific-attribute-valu) describes a slightly more complicated case (finding an object with a given `name:` in a list of maps) but I've written a recursive-template approach that would work for this case as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze, we've talked about this before :). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66497769/how-to-use-printf-in-this-helm-template-function. I used that trick and it worked like a charm! If you put that as an answer here I'll accept it too. Or mark this as a dup.